# How to easily create hyperlink to activity (with intent) in TextView

Tags: android, hyperlink, textview, click

I would like to hyperlink any text that goes to imgur.com to open a new activity in my application (with intent). Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: Have you tried something ? please post code that you have tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="http://www.imgur.com"
    android:autoLink="web"
    android:id="@+id/textView"/>
```

this will open a pop up for the link you have given in text

Comment: I have multiple intent types though, should have clarified. There are more activities that I would like to open depending on the link context (image fullscreen, image albums, integrated web browser for others, youtube videos, etc)

Comment: then you can use intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND); or intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SHARE);

Comment: Thanks for the info. I used your code to do autoLink and then created my own MovementMethod to open the activities based on the clicked URL. Thanks!